# Why when implementing clone method we return super.clone() not this clone()

Tags: java

```
public abstract class Shape implements Cloneable {

   private String id;
   protected String type;

   abstract void draw();

   public String getType(){
      return type;
   }

   public String getId() {
      return id;
   }

   public void setId(String id) {
      this.id = id;
   }

   public Object clone() {
      Object clone = null;

      try {
         clone = super.clone();

      } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

      return clone;
   }
}
```

Suppose i want to get a clone of an object then why we always return `super.clone()` .if i want to clone an object then i suppose this is the object i want to clone.I am a beginner at cloning.

Comment: [here](http://coderevisited.com/cloneable-interface-in-java/) you could find an explanation with proper examples.

Comment: `this.clone()` is plain recursion. You'll get a `StackOverflowError`. `super.clone();` is very similar to `super()` in a constructor. Clone methods must be chained.

Answer (score 3):

The superclass `clone` method should be `Object.clone()` or it should delegate<sup>1</sup> (ultimately) to `Object.clone()`.  That is a "magic" method that knows how to create a new instance of the *actual* class of the current instance.

And, of course, if you were to try to implement clone like this:

```
public Object clone() {
    return clone();
}
```

you would create a recursion loop that would quickly end with a `StackOverflowError`.

---

<sup>1 - If `super.clone()` does not ultimately delegate to `Object.clone()`, then it won't be able to clone the value of the fields defined by `Shape` and its concrete subtypes.</sup>

---

Note that this particular example, the `clone()` could be simplified to this:

```
public Object clone() {
    return super.clone();
}
```

The `Shape` class has `Object` as its superclass, and the only case where `Object.clone()` will throw `CloneNotSupportedException` is if the actual class did not `implement` the `Cloneable` interface.  But `Shape` does that itself.

In fact. all this declaration of `clone()` is *really* doing is to increase the visibility of the `protected` version of `clone()` in the `Object` API.

Comment: `Object.clone()` makes a magic, but `super` in this context may not be an `Object`

Comment: Yes.  You are right.  (I was correcting that ...) However, if `super.clone()` doesn't delegate to `Object.clone()` this implementation does not work!

Comment: @AndrewTobilko - And in this case, we *know* that the supertype of `Shape` is `Object`.  See how it is declared.

Answer (score 1):

The object that is dereferenced is the same, whether you use `super` or `this`. However, since you're overriding the `clone` method using `this.clone()` would lead to (infinite) recursion. Using `super.clone()` you make sure to call the `clone` implementation of the superclass.

Note that `Object.clone` copies the whole object, regardless of the actual type.

The only thing that you need to take care of when overriding the method is:

- increasing the visibility to `public` (if you want that)
- copying any mutable objects referenced from the class that were not copied by `super.clone()`

---

The following example shows the usual way of cloning a object

```
public class Sheep implements Cloneable {

    private String name;

    public Sheep(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        Sheep s = new Sheep("dolly");
        Sheep s2 = (Sheep) s.clone();
        s2.numbers[0] = 42;
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println(s2);
    }

    private int[] numbers = new int[1];

    @Override
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        Sheep clone = (Sheep) super.clone();

        // copy referenced mutable objects
        clone.numbers = this.numbers.clone();

        // no need to copy name, since String is immutable

        return clone;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Sheep{" + "name=" + name + ", numbers=" + Arrays.toString(numbers) + '}';
    }

}
```

Note that commenting out the line

```
clone.numbers = this.numbers.clone();
```

will lead to the arrays being the same.

Answer (score 1):

In your example `super.clone()` refers to `Object.clone()` whose JavaDoc states:

> Otherwise, this method creates a new instance of the class of this object and initializes all its fields with exactly the contents of the corresponding fields of this object, as if by assignment; the contents of the fields are not themselves cloned. Thus, this method performs a "shallow copy" of this object, not a "deep copy" operation.

That means that if a shallow copy is sufficient then using `super.clone()` is sufficient. The override serves 2 purposes here:

- make `clone()` public (`Object.clone()` is protected)
- handle cases where a subclass doesn't implement `Cloneable` gracefully by printing the stacktrace and returning `null`.